Docker-compose: Creating same container for different projects
I'm facing an issue with my Django projects that have a similar structure. Each project has a backend folder containing a docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.
The structure is as follows:
project1/backend/docker-compose.yml project2.backend/docker-compose.yml 
The problem arises when I switch between projects and run docker-compose up. It seems that the container named backend is reusing services from the previous project instead of creating a new container.
Here's an example of the docker-compose.yml for each project:
Project 1:
version: '3.9'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: project_name
      POSTGRES_DB: project_name
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A project_name worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/webapp
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

  celery-beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A project_name beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/webapp
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Project 2:
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/webapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    # Added Command for hot reloading in dev server
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  postgres:
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: project_name
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes: 
  postgres-data:

Here's an example of the Dockerfile for each project
Project1:
# Use Python 3.11 slim image
FROM python:3.11-slim as base

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-dev libpq-dev gcc \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create and set working directory
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

# Install Pipenv
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -q 'pipenv==2023.12.0'

# Copy Pipfile and Pipfile.lock
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /opt/webapp/

# Install project dependencies
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . /opt/webapp

# Separate stage for release
FROM base as release

# Copy built files from the base stage
COPY --from=base /opt/webapp /opt/webapp

# Set environment variables and collect static files
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
ARG SECRET_KEY
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --settings=project_name.settings.development

# Default command to run the server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]


Project2:
FROM python:3.8-slim as base

# libpq-dev and python3-dev help with psycopg2
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3-dev libpq-dev gcc curl \
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
WORKDIR /opt/webapp
COPY Pipfile* /opt/webapp/

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -q 'pipenv==2018.11.26'
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system
COPY . /opt/webapp

FROM base as release

COPY --from=base /root/.local /root/.local
COPY --from=base /opt/webapp/manage.py /opt/webapp/manage.py


WORKDIR /opt/webapp
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
ARG SECRET_KEY 
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Run the image as a non-root user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" django
USER django
CMD waitress-serve --port=$PORT project_name.wsgi:application


I want to ensure that each project creates its own separate container instead of reusing the existing backend container. How can I achieve this while maintaining the current project structure? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have given container names for each service but it has not helped me, I want an idea of how to differentiate these two projects and create different containers for each project.

Are both Compose files in subdirectories named backend?  Compose uses that directory name as its project name, and if both projects have the same directory basename, they can conflict like what you're describing.  What is the purpose of -p, --project-name option in docker-compose command has a little more discussion of this.

Try renaming services/container names in docker-compose.yml file, like "project1_postgres:...", "project1_redis:...".
I believe you can also "docker-compose down -v" to remove anonymous volumes, but I think the startup time will be longer.
If this doesn't work, you can also try to add a network to your specific project, so that services will speak to eachother only if they are in the same network
networks:
  custom_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - custom_network


one more, now I see that your both projects main folder is "backend", docker is using the directory name as the default project name. You can also try something like this docker-compose -p project1 up.
I hope one of 4 will work, gl :)

docker-compose -p project1 up this command is worked for partition my projects, thanks for your effort.
